# PHP Validating Submit

Tags: php

I'm working on a project where a user can click on an item. If the user clicked at it before , then when he tries to click at it again it shouldn't work or INSERT value on the DB. When I click the first item(I'm displaying the items straight from database by id) it inserts into DB and then when I click at it again it works(gives me the error code) doesn't insert into DB. All other items when I click at them , even if I click for the second, third, fourth time all of it inserts into DB. Please help guys. Thanks

```
<?php

session_start();
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

include("php/connect.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 3";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {

    $username = $_SESSION['username'];

    $submit = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["submit"]);

    $tests = $_POST["test"];

    // If the user submitted the form.
    // Do the updating on the database.
    if (!empty($submit)) {
        if (count($tests) > 0) {
            foreach ($tests as $test_id => $test_value) {
                $match = "SELECT user_id, match_id FROM match_select";
                $row1 = mysql_query($match)or die(mysql_error());
                while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($row1)) {
                    $user_match = $row2["user_id"];
                    $match = $row2['match_id'];
                }
                if ($match == $test_id) {
                    echo "You have already bet.";
                } else {
                    switch ($test_value) {
                        case 1:
                            mysql_query("UPDATE test SET win = win + 1 WHERE id = '$test_id'");
                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO match_select (user_id, match_id) VALUES ('1','$test_id')");
                        break;
                        case 'X':
                            mysql_query("UPDATE test SET draw = draw + 1 WHERE id = '$test_id'");
                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO match_select (user_id, match_id) VALUES ('1','$test_id')");
                        break;

                        case 2:
                            mysql_query("UPDATE test SET lose = lose + 1 WHERE id = '$test_id'");
                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO match_select (user_id, match_id) VALUES ('1','$test_id')"); 
                        break;
                        default:

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<h2>Seria A</h2><hr/>
        <br/>Welcome,".$username."! <a href='php/logout.php'><b>LogOut</b></a><br/>";

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

        $id = $row['id'];
        $home = $row['home'];
        $away = $row['away'];
        $win = $row['win'];
        $draw = $row['draw'];
        $lose = $row['lose'];

        echo "<br/>",$id,") " ,$home, " - ", $away;

        echo "
            <form action='seria.php' method='post'>
                <select name='test[$id]'>        
                    <option value=\"\">Parashiko</option>
                    <option value='1'>1</option>
                    <option value='X'>X</option>
                    <option value='2'>2</option>
                </select>
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/>
                <br/>
            </form>
            <br/>";        

        echo "Totali ", $sum = $win+$lose+$draw, "<br/><hr/>";
    }
} else {
  $error = "<div id='hello'>Duhet te besh Log In qe te vendosesh parashikime ndeshjesh<br/><a href='php/login.php'>Kycu Ketu</a></div>";
}

?>
```

Comment: How does your error code look like? What exactly is not working? Did you debug your code with `error_reporting(E_ALL);` etc.?

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: submit in /home/content/16/11285316/html/seria.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: test in /home/content/16/11285316/html/seria.php on line 19

Comment: i dont think those lines have anything to do with my problem ?

Comment: well it says that `$_POST['test']` doesn't exist. Which means that your code would stop working at the line `if(count($tests) > 0)` because `$tests` is `null`

Comment: Your if condition is not in the while loop, keep it there and fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here :

```
$match = "SELECT user_id, match_id FROM match_select";
$row1 = mysql_query($match)or die(mysql_error());
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($row1)) {
    $user_match = $row2["user_id"];
    $match = $row2['match_id'];
}
```

You are not checking it correctly. You have to check if the entry in `match_select` exists for the `user_id` and the `match_id` concerned. Otherwise, `$match` would always be equal to the `match_id` field of the last inserted row in your database :

```
$match = "SELECT * 
    FROM `match_select` 
    WHERE `user_id` = '<your_id>'
    AND `match_id` = '$test_id'";
$matchResult = mysql_query($match)or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($matchResult)) {
    echo "You have already bet.";
}
```

By the way, consider using `PDO` or `mysqli` for manipulating database. `mysql_` functions are deprecated :

http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: Thanks brother it works .. but now i have another problem .. I include pictures.. Normal page ---> http://postimg.org/image/dw7gjy63l/  ... The new error page ----> http://postimg.org/image/8yxdbkjbr/ ...(it shows all the number of times on the db a entry entered

Comment: @Henri It seems like you are re-inserting entries to `test` table somewhere, but I can't see it in the code you posted.

Comment: its in the switch statement the whole thing.. i dont have other code that inserts things into test

Comment: I'll take a look, but this seems strange. It is another issue.

Comment: @Henri Ho yes... lol. I get it. I used a `$result` variable. Replace it with `$matchResult` or something else :)

Comment: Thanks man ... Very Very Helpful .. Switching to PDO For database aswell

Answer (score 0):

validate insertion of record by looking up on the table if the data already exists.

Simplest way for example is to

```
 $query = "SELECT * FROM match_select WHERE user_id = '$user_id'";
 $result = mysql_query($query);

 if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
   // do not insert
 }
 else
 {
   // do something here..
 }
```

Comment: why query for an `ID` with a full text search `LIKE`statement? Why not just use `WHERE user_id = $user_id`

Answer (score 0):

In your form you have `<select name='test[$id]'>` (one for each item), then when you submit the form you are getting `$tests = $_POST["test"];` You don't need to specify the index in the form and can simply do `<select name='test[]'>`, you can eventually add a hidden field with the id with `<input type="hidden" value="$id"/>`. The second part is the verification wich is not good at the moment; you can simply check if the itemalready exist in the database with a query

Comment: `<input type="hidden">$id</input>` should be `<input type="hidden" value="$id" />`